# How to route to a view on button click (ExtJS 6.2)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

So i have created two views : one a login dialog and the other (the following) is a dashboard basically.
On login click i use `this.redirectTo("dashboard",true);` hoping that it will trigger the routing linked handler in the next view (the following) but it didn't work; so I set the trigger manually and trigger the handler using an instance of the view.

```
   Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboard', {
            extend: 'Ext.Container',
            alias: 'widget.newDashboard',
            id: 'project1',
             routes:{
                     '#dashboard':{
                         action:'onDashboardView'
                     }
                     },
             onDashboardView:function(){
                    var dash =  Ext.create('widget.newDashboard', {
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    hideMode: 'visibility'
                 });
                              dash.show();
             },....
```

My question is how to do the routing properly like in the described first way so that the first displays when the URL changes to include the '#dashboard' part?

UPDATE2 : for now previous and next of the browser are doing nothing.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making progress.  Remove the hash from the routes

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboard', {
            extend: 'Ext.Container',
            alias: 'widget.newDashboard',
            id: 'project1',
             routes:{
                     'dashboard':{     // REMOVE THE #
                         action:'onDashboardView'
                     }
                     },
             onDashboardView:function(dash){
  
                              dash.show();
             },....
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/39oc&view/editor)

[Fiddle - see the url change](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/39oc/preview)

Comment: Thanks but still as i mentioned it still doesn't trigger the onDashboardView handler the fact that i redirect the URL to '/dashboard' : which is how the routing is supposed to work right ?

Comment: PLS SEE EDIT : i was hoping that when i redirect to a new URL ("/dashboard") the onDashboardView would trigger automatically displaying the new view.

Comment: are you calling the redirectTo("dashboard") function on your conroller?  This will modify the hash on the url and fire the onDashboardView method.

Comment: See your next post.  I put a fiddle that shows how it should be done. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/39oc&view/editor